# Applying logic to a nested append function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a one to one correspondence between the values of a dictionary `d`and `df1` to which I created a dataframe of appended items.

The line `df11` is currently hardcoded because I know the number of keys in my `d`, ie, I specifically write append 3 times with its corresponding `df.loc[n]` in`df11`

Input:

```
Sn=['1','2','3']
Dn=['X','Y','Z']

d={}
for num1 in Sn:
    for num2 in Dn:
        key = f'Sn{num1}{num2}'
        value = pd.DataFrame({'A':[f'-{num1}O{num2}-']})
        d[key] = value

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[45,23,76]})
df11=d['Sn1X'].append(df1.loc[0]).append(d['Sn1Y']).append(df1.loc[1])
```

Output:`df1`

```
    A
0   45
1   23
2   76
```

Output:`df11`

```
        A
0   -1OX-
0   45
0   -1OY-
1   23
```

How would I apply logic to `df11` for `n` number of keys given in the dictionary/df1?
For example I would have to add additional appends to get the last row in 'df1`

```
dfF=d['Sn1X'].append(df1.loc[0]).append(d['Sn1Y']).append(df1.loc[1]).append(d['Sn1Z']).append(df1.loc[2])
```

Output:`dfF`

```
       A
0   -1OX-
0   45
0   -1OY-
1   23
0   -1OZ-
2   76
```

Comment: Why do you need the dictionary? If you have some content in form of lists, it should be logically possible to get desired output into a dataframe. I think it would help if you could explain instead what you're trying to achieve

Comment: because my real data will have 54 keys in `d` and my input dataframes are coming from excel sheets. The elements in `df1` will actually be a series extracted from the excel sheets. My posted question is simplified as much as possible.

Comment: Im looking for a way to apply logic to `dfF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, all you want is a generalized code that can handle `n` number of keys.

This piece of code should do the trick

```py
tmp = pd.Series([], dtype=object)
keys = list(d.keys())
for i, cell in enumerate(df1.iterrows()):
    # d[keys[i]] contains a Dataframe 
    # cell[1] contains a series 
    # you append these together and then keep appending to an empty series 'tmp' 
    tmp = tmp.append(d[keys[i]].append(cell[1])) # updated
tmp.drop(columns=0, inplace=True)
#tmp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(tmp)
```

Output

```
       A
0  -1OX-
0     45
0  -1OY-
1     23
0  -1OZ-
2     76
```

Comment: that looks promising just that I am getting an error `list object is not callable` for `keys = list(d.keys())`

Comment: make sure that you do not have any variable named **list**, that's a keyword in python and you will be shadowing it

Comment: that works! Great I will study the code now. Perhaps I will have questions later. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what this line is doing `for i, cell in enumerate(df.iterrows()):` particularly `cell`. I dont see it being called anywhere...

Comment: You could replace `df1.loc[i]` with `cell`. I must have forgotten

Comment: doing so I get `cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'int'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`